# Deploying Laravel 10 + Inertia + Vue on Laragon for internal application

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-10, laragon

I'm creating an in house web application for a small business using Laravel 10 + Inertia + Vue. I deployed the application to a Laragon web server in 1 of the company PC.
So what I've done is to run npm run build on my project, then copy to Laragon folder. Here's the folder structure that I have made to make it works.

```
- laragon
    - [ default folders of Laragon ]
    - lib (all Laravel related files go here)
        - [ folders of Laravel application ]
        - public (hot file deleted)
    - www
        - [ Here I copy all the contents from lib/public,
          then change the path inside index.php to point to /lib folders.
          Here I also delete the hot file ]
```

The problem is, every time I need to do update, I need to run npm run build, then copy the `build` folder inside my development `public` folder to `/lib/public` **AND** `/www`. While for the Laravel related files, I can just push via git.

I'm not sure if this is the best practice. But it works. I'm wondering if anybody has a better suggestion for me to ease the update deployment process.
Thanks in advance.